# Slow Sums Algorithm

Tags: algorithm

Suppose we have a list of N numbers and repeat the following operation until we're left with only a single number: Choose any two consecutive numbers and replace them with their sum. Moreover, we associate a penalty with each operation equal to the value of the new number and call the penalty for the entire list as the sum of the penalties of each operation.

Note: Consecutive numbers means that their indices in the array are consecutive, not that their values are consecutive.
For example, given the list [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], we could choose 2 and 3 for the first operation, which would transform the list into [1, 5, 4, 5] and incur a penalty of 5. The goal in this problem is to find the worst possible penalty for a given input.

Constraints:
1 ≤ N ≤ 10^6
1 ≤ Ai ≤ 10^7, where *Ai denotes the ith initial element of an array.
The sum of values of N over all test cases will not exceed 5 * 10^6.

```
Example
arr = [4, 2, 1, 3]
output = 23
First, add 4 + 2 for a penalty of 6. Now the array is [6, 1, 3]
Add 6 + 1 for a penalty of 7. Now the array is [7, 3]
Add 7 + 3 for a penalty of 10. The penalties sum to 23.
```

```
int getTotalTime(int[] arr) {}
```

Comment: Could you post all of the contents in your question? External links can die, and your question would be incomplete.

Comment: You are looking for the fastest algorithm? Or what is your aim?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a greedy problem. The key behind it is to notice that we have to always follow the biggest sum possible in each iteration. In your case `[4, 2, 1, 3]`, the first biggest sum is `6`, then `7` and then `10`.

The problem comes when the biggest sum appears multiple times, for example `[5, 3, 7, 1]`, then you have to choose if it's better to start with `[5, 3]` or `[7, 1]`.

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int n = 6;                       //array size
int a[] = {2, 1, 7, 1, 5, 3};    //array

vector<pair<int, int>> v;        //positions we will analyse

void analyse(){                  //this method gets the positions with biggest sum
    int sum = 0;
    for(int i = 1; i < n; i++) sum = max(sum, a[i - 1] + a[i]);
    for(int i = 1; i < n; i++) if(a[i - 1] + a[i] == sum) v.push_back(make_pair(i - 1, i));
}

int evaluate_penalty(int i, int j){   //given a position, this method finds
    int l = i, r = j;                 //the biggest penalty starting there
    int penalty = a[i] + a[j];
    int val = penalty;
    while(i != 0 || j != n - 1){
        if(l > 0 && r < n - 1) {
            if(a[l - 1] > a[r + 1]) l--;
            else r++;
        }
        else if(l > 0) l--;
        else r++;

        val += (l != i ? a[l] : 0) + (r != j ? a[r] : 0);
        penalty += val;
        i = l; j = r;
    }
    return penalty;
}

int max_penalty(){            //this method finds the biggest penalty
    v.clear();                //within all the possible starting positions.
    analyse();
    int maxPenalty = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < v.size(); i++){
        maxPenalty = max(maxPenalty, evaluate_penalty(v[i].first, v[i].second));
    }
    return maxPenalty;
}

int main(){
    cout<<max_penalty()<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

The complexity is **O(n²)**, BUT in most of the cases, it will be **O(n)**. Given that the biggest sum between two consecutive numbers is **s**, the complexity relies on how many pairs of consecutive numbers sum **s**. If there is only one (like in your example `[4, 2, 1, 3]`, it will finish in one iteration, hence O(n). If the array is something like `[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, ..., 1]`, it will take O(n²).

Comment: Yeah, that looks like almost my solution. Dunno if there is a better approach or not but at least it confirms mine. Thanks

Comment: You will never go into the following loop, because at the beginning vector v is empty:

 for(int i = 0; i < v.size(); i++){

Comment: In your example [5, 3, 7, 1] biggest sum is 7+5, so no need to select which is better to pick first. I think your solution adds unnecessary complexity. If you sort the array, you'd always pick the two greatest numbers first and have the higher penalty each time. Complexity is N log N.

Comment: Does it pass 2 20 1 19 ?

Answer (score 4):

Another Javascript solution that covers the given test cases

```
function getTotalTime(arr) {
  arr.sort();
  var sum = arr[arr.length-1];
  var penalty = 0;
  for(let i=arr.length-2; i>=0; i-- ) {
    sum +=arr[i];
    penalty += sum;
  }
  return penalty;
}
```

Comment: this does not work: you can merge only adjacent elements.

Comment: The question stated:  two consecutive numbers! Your answer is for another different question for "worst" possible penalty.

Comment: if I sort the array in-place, then they will be adjacent

Answer (score 0):

I have solved it like this but not sure if it's optimal or not

```
static int getTotalTime(int[] arr) {
        List<Integer> output = new ArrayList<>();
        Arrays.stream(arr).forEach(output::add);
        if (output.size() < 3) {
            return output.stream().reduce((a, b) -> a + b).get();
        }

        int sum = 0;
        List<Integer> max1 = new ArrayList<>();
        max1.add(0);
        for (int i = 2; i < output.size(); i++) {
            if (output.get(i) + output.get(i - 1) > output.get(max1.get(0)) + output.get(max1.get(0) + 1)) {
                max1 = new ArrayList<>();
                max1.add(i - 1);
            }else if (output.get(i) + output.get(i - 1) == output.get(max1.get(0)) + output.get(max1.get(0) + 1)) {
                max1.add(i - 1);
            }
        }

        sum = sum + output.get(max1.get(0)) + output.get(max1.get(0) + 1);

        List newList = new ArrayList(output);
        newList.set(max1.get(0), output.get(max1.get(0)) + output.get(max1.get(0) + 1));
        newList.remove(max1.get(0) + 1);

        int remainingSum = getTotalTime(newList);

        for (int i = 1; i < max1.size(); i++) {
            newList = new ArrayList(output);
            newList.set(max1.get(i), output.get(max1.get(i)) + output.get(max1.get(i) + 1));
            newList.remove(max1.get(i) + 1);
            int nextRemainingSum = getTotalTime(newList);
            if (nextRemainingSum > remainingSum) {
                remainingSum = nextRemainingSum;
            }
        }

        sum += remainingSum;

        return sum;
    }

    static int getTotalTime(List<Integer> output) {
        int sum = 0;
        while (output.size() > 2) {
            int max1 = 0;
            for (int i = 2; i < output.size(); i++) {
                if (output.get(i) + output.get(i - 1) > output.get(max1) + output.get(max1 + 1)) {
                    max1 = i - 1;
                }
            }
            sum += output.get(max1) + output.get(max1 + 1);
            output.set(max1, output.get(max1) + output.get(max1 + 1));
            output.remove(max1 + 1);
        }

        return sum + output.stream().reduce((a, b) -> a + b).get();

    }
```

Comment: As you question concerns the algorithm, you could explain what it the algorithm that you implement in this program. No need to enter in too many details.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an optimized solution in Javascript including a couple of test cases. The key principle is that the highest penalty can be obtained in each step by adding the two largest elements in the array.

```
//Begin Solution
function getTotalTime(arr) {
    function getTotal(a){
      if(a.length==2)
        return a[0]+a[1]
      else{
        const penalty = a[a.length-1]+a[a.length-2]
        return penalty+getTotal([...a.slice(0,a.length-2),penalty])
      }
          
    }
  return getTotal(arr.slice(0,arr.length).sort((a,b)=>a-b))
}
 //End Solution

  // These are the tests we use to determine if the solution is correct.

  function printInteger(n) {
    var out = '[' + n + ']';
    return out;
  }
  
  var test_case_number = 1;
  
  function check(expected, output) {
    var result = (expected == output);
    var rightTick = "\u2713";
    var wrongTick = "\u2717";
    if (result) {
      var out = rightTick + ' Test #' + test_case_number;
      console.log(out);
    }
    else {
      var out = '';
      out += wrongTick + ' Test #' + test_case_number + ': Expected ';
      out += printInteger(expected);
      out += ' Your output: ';
      out += printInteger(output);
      console.log(out);
    }
    test_case_number++;
  }
  
  var arr_1 = [4, 2, 1, 3];
  var expected_1 = 26;
  var output_1 = getTotalTime(arr_1);
  check(expected_1, output_1);
  
  var arr_2 = [2, 3, 9, 8, 4];
  var expected_2 = 88;
  var output_2 = getTotalTime(arr_2);
  check(expected_2, output_2);
```

Answer (score -2):

There is better and simple solution for this problem using MaxHeap.

```
int getTotalPenalty (int[] arr) {
    PriorityQueue<Integer> q = new PriorityQueue<>(Collections.reverseOrder());
    for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        q.add(arr[i]);
    }
    int totalP = 0;
    while(q.size() > 1) {
        int penality =  q.poll() + q.poll();
        totalP = totalP + penality;
        q.add(penality);
    }
    return totalP;
}
```

Comment: This is not a valid solution because the stated problem requires us to use two consecutive elements, not any two elements.  The solution you've written here is similar to the solution for Minimum Cost to Connect Sticks, except in that problem we use a min heap, not a max heap.